# How to display the user id in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a function in which I have to, among other things, pass to the template the ids of the users who conducted the correspondence, but I get an error in the line:

```
pk_list = messages.values('user_from__pk').distinct()
```

views.py:

```
def send_chat(request):
    resp = {}
    User = get_user_model()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post =request.POST
        u_from = UserModel.objects.get(id=post['user_from'])
        u_to = UserModel.objects.get(id=post['user_to'])
        messages = request.user.received.all()
        pk_list = messages.values('user_from__pk').distinct()
        correspondents = get_user_model().objects.filter(pk__in=list(pk_list))
        insert = chatMessages(user_from=u_from,user_to=u_to,message=post['message'],correspondents=correspondents)
        try:
            insert.save()
            resp['status'] = 'success'
        except Exception as ex:
            resp['status'] = 'failed'
            resp['mesg'] = ex
    else:
        resp['status'] = 'failed'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), content_type="application/json")
```

models.py:

```
class chatMessages(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="sent")
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="received")
    message = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    correspondents = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="correspondents", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got {'user_from__pk': 1}.
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: `pk_list = messages.values_list('user_from__pk', flat=True).distinct()`  and then `correspondents = get_user_model().objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is here:

```
pk_list = messages.values('user_from__pk').distinct()
```

queryset.values give you a list of dictionaries. in your case `[{'user_from__pk': pk1}, {'user_from__pk': pk2},... e.t.c.]`

more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values

And you need `values_list`.

```
pk_list = messages.values_list('user_from__pk', flat=True).distinct()
```

To avoid joins - you can do:

```
pk_list = messages.values_list('user_from_pk', flat=True).distinct()
```

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list